# Display images from URL in a Detailviewcontroller with Tableviewcontroller as a parent

Tags: image, uitableview, url, detailview

Hard to explain, but I'll try;

I am making an app for showing roadcameras. I have a TableViewController which leads to a DetailViewController.
What I want to achieve is that when I click on Row 1 it shows the picture from www.url1.com. If I click on Row 2, it shows the picture from www.url2.com, and so on. I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

I first started by using this code:

```
_place = @[@"E6 Minnesund",
          @"E6 Heia"];

_url = @[@"http://webkamera.vegvesen.no/kamera?id=450848",
         @"http://webkamera.vegvesen.no/kamera?id=100102"];
```

But stopped because I couldn't see how I could get this working...

Any ideas?

And please don't just rate the post down because you think its stupid. I'm kinda new to Xcode and for me, this is hard. Thanks in advance

I can post the whole project folder if necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just write the code in didselectrowAtIndexPath

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 DetailViewController *picker = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
picker.row=indexPath.row;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:picker];

}
```

and in DetailViewController

---

in .h

---

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
{

}
@property(nonatomic,assign)int row;
```

in .m

---

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

 dispatch_queue_t myqueue = dispatch_queue_create("myqueue", NULL);

    // execute a task on that queue asynchronously
    dispatch_async(myqueue, ^{
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[_url objectAtIndex:row];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
Image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data]; //UI updates should be done on the main thread

UIImageView * myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[self.view addSubview:myImageView];
     });
    });
```

Comment: Dang... I can't get it working, just getting several errors. Do you mind setting up a working project and send it? Then I (and others) can see exactly what you did :)

Comment: dude where are you getting error i have given enough code. tell me where exactly you are getting error?

Comment: DetailViewController:
"Use of undeclared identifier 'row'" - 
"Use of undeclared identifier 'image'" - 
"Use of undeclared identifier 'image'" again.

TableViewController.m:
"No visible @interface for 'UINavigationController' declares the selector 'pushViewController:'"

Do I need some TableCell files as well?

Comment: Here is the project file if you want to take a closer look; https://mega.co.nz/#!AQ0WGAjI!BxkWq8kLyUpfXJdhipykltzm31NilkyFtdUwR-kRkCs

Really appreciate your help

Comment: your link is not working.ok dude it is the link for working code i created especially for you  https://github.com/murali9/TableviewToDetailView

Comment: errors and solutions: you have to declare image as uimage, and for navigation you have to embeded UInavigationcontroller.but in my code i just used presentViewController

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to mix it into my main project and see how it goes, thanks again :) I'll let you guys know how it's working soon